# Compartilhar tipos entre API e aplicação cliente

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma API REST usando ***ASP.NET WebApi 2*** e, como venho do velho padrão SOAP, estou acostumado com o compartilhamento de tipos entre a API e o cliente. Isto é, ao referenciar o meu serviço no projeto cliente, todos os tipos que são usados na API são criados no projeto cliente.

Estive pensando em como fazer algo parecido, e consegui pensar em três alternativas:

1. Duplicar o código entre API e cliente
2. Criar um pacote nuget com os tipos (compilado ou talvez o próprio arquivo `.cs`)
3. Usar `anonymous types` quando for fazer requisições **`POST, PUT, etc.`** e usar `dynamic` para requisições do tipo **`GET`** e afins

   **GET:**

   ```
   var clienteResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
   WriteLine(clienteResponse.Id);
   ```

   **POST:**

   ```
   var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
              {
                  Nome = "Jéferson",
                  Idade = 30                
              });

   req.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
   var response = client.Execute(req);
   ```

Essa é a melhor forma de se trabalhar? Caso sim, existe alguma outra forma (ou algum padrão) de compartilhar estes tipos?

Comment: TL;DR: Se a plataforma cliente for *strong typed*, compartilhe os tipos. Caso não (web/javascript, por exemplo) nem se importe com isso.

Comment: Então, pretendo ter várias plataformas cliente. A maioria são aplicações **winforms** e algumas *javascript*. @lbotinelly

Comment: Se winforms, e na mesma linguagem, um serializador/desserializador simples resolve seus problemas, mesmo se tipos não forem fortemente especificados. A interface `ApiController` do WinApi 2, por exemplo, mapeia propriedades de objetos JSON para as propriedades de uma nova instância do objeto.

Comment: Opinativamente falando, eu seria a favor de usar os tipos, e não necessariamente usando o NuGet (faria uma Class Library para ambos). A dependência de um NuGet pode ser interessante se os objetos de serialização não mudarem muito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Não tem como dizer qual seria a "melhor forma" de fazer isso, daria uma margem enorme para opinião, então tentarei expressar os prós e contras de cada forma.

Antes de olhar para isso você deve ver se irá ou não compartilhar os tipos entre o servidor e os clientes. Existem alguns fatores que podem influenciar nessa decisão, como versionamento, erros de tipos (quebrando o cliente assim), duplicação de código, possíveis erros ao manter os dados entre o cliente e o servidor, etc. Esses fatores podem influenciar se você irá ou não compartilhar os tipos de dados.

Se resolveu por compartilhar, você teria as duas opções que mostrou, duplicar o código ou realizar o versionamento por dll's/pacotes.

#### Duplicar Código

**Prós:**

- Utilizando essa forma você está garantindo que a tipagem será a mesma
  entre as aplicações, não causando assim problemas de tipagem;
- Não terá problemas com serialização/descerialização pois os tipos serão os mesmos;

**Contras:**

- Duplicação de código;
- Possível erro de tipos que causará em problemas da aplicação;
- Maior trabalho para manter os códigos atualizados;

#### Pacote NuGet

Você tem a mesma estrutura que se fosse duplicar o código, porém possui a facilidade de versionamento, deixando assim menos propenso a erros, garantindo uma "segurança" para a comunicação entre as aplicações.

Por exemplo, se você tem a versão 1.5.6 no cliente e no servidor possuir a 1.6 possivelmente terá alguns problemas. Com o versionamento você sabe o que mudou e se ocasionou problemas, sabe como corrigir.

Agora, se você não optar por compartilhar os tipos, você terá um cenário diferente.

#### Dynamic Types

Utilizando esta forma você não estaria compartilhando os tipos entre o cliente e o servidor, isto é, explicitamente. Uma possível modificação no servidor não iria "quebrar" o cliente, e vice-versa.

**Prós:**

- Modelo do cliente está menos ligado com o servidor, espelhando apenas a saída, mas não os tipos;
- O Servidor pode ser modificado sem risco para os clientes;
- Permite melhorias em qualquer lado (cliente-server) sem "quebrar" a aplicação.
- Não se preocupa com os tipos;

**Contras:**

- Você não possui um contrato entre o cliente e o servidor;
- Não se sabe quando possui alguma mudança significativa que poderá ocasionar problemas;
- Cliente e Servidor com versões diferentes é mais complexo achar um erro que que eventualmente poderia acontecer;
- Não se preocupa com os tipos;

Observe que não se preocupar com os tipos está em prós em contras. A forma que você for tratar os dados que decidirá se será pró ou contra.

**Conclusão**

Utilizando tipagem definida entre os sistemas garantirá um acoplamento maior, deixando assim mais "segurança", se é que essa seja a palavra. Porém, poderá ter problemas caso tenha algum tipo diferente entre as aplicações. Já sem a tipagem definida você terá "problemas" de versionamento e tipagem fraca. Não tem como dar certeza que terá esses problemas, e sim que são possíveis problemas que poderão aparecer no decorrer do projeto.

Não existe uma forma "melhor" de fazer isso. Não sabemos do seu projeto nem como isso seria aplicado no cenário de sua aplicação.

---

Existe algumas bibliotecas que ~prometem~ aceitar os dois tipos, a [Expando](https://github.com/RickStrahl/Expando) é uma delas. [Neste link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Feb/08/Creating-a-dynamic-extensible-C-Expando-Object) você possui um tutorial caso queira verificar o seu funcionamento.

**Nota:** Independente das opções você está compartilhando os tipos, a diferença é que uma está explicito e a outra não.

Referências:

- [Usando Nuget para dar Web API que Adicionar serviço experiência de Referência](http://www.bizcoder.com/using-nuget-to-give-web-api-that-add-service-reference-experience);
- [Devo compartilhar tipos entre um serviço Web API e seu cliente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050502/4843158);
- [WebPack](http://www.bizcoder.com/webpack)
- [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dynamic)

<sub>*EU possuo uma certa queda por versionar em pacotes para maior controle entre os sistemas. Dessa forma saberei exatamente o que mudou e onde foi alterado. Caso aconteça algum problema, saberei onde corrigir.*</sub>